# "Expected expression before '{' token"

Tags: objective-c, button

I may be missing something silly. But I've been staring at it for a day now and re-working it and what not. I still get the same "Expected expression before '{' token" error.

Before I got this error I was having trouble getting my button to do what I was asking it to do, which was simply add the two numbers and display the answer, basically. Here's the bit of code giving me the problem:

```
-(IBAction)click:(id)sender {   
    int sum = [myInt1.text intValue] + [myInt2.text intValue];
    label.text = {NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ the answer is %d",
        name.text, sum];
}
```

Comment: In this case, it was easy to tell that you were asking about objectve c after i entered it because of the code snippet, but it's generally a good idea to put the language you're using as a tag (like i did), in the title, or in the first part of the question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Replace:

```
label.text = {NSString ...
```

with:

```
label.text = [NSString ...
```

(the parenthesis before NSString).

Comment: wow. it really was something that silly. thank you very much. the button still isnt working, but at least i got the error to go away :)

Comment: Everyone makes these mistakes, and sometimes they can hide out for hours! In fact, i didn't really see that error...

Comment: you're welcome. These are sort of typos that make you really bang your head against a keyboard (or wall) once you find what you typed wrong ,)

Comment: It happens to me all the time, I miss the small stuff. I'm kinda new to objective-c and I'm still working out the kinks. Could I ask if someone could kindly take a look at my code and maybe give me an idea of what Im missing to make the button work?